# Mongo aggregate multiple distinct

Tags: mongodb

I want to refactor an old `php/mongo` code to use `MongoDB's` aggregation functionality.
Now, I am doing lot of queries to extract data as I want.

This is the document model:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("548eb89c7a9a83fc0000002c"),
  "session" : "870922750",
  "id_category" : 1118,
  "id_subcategory" : 2453,
  "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-15T12:31:55Z")
}
```

And, I need to aggregate data by distinct `session` field and by `subcategory` count per day.
As far I can think, the return should be something like:

```
id_subcategory
days
  day 
  count (distinct session)

  day
  count (distinct session)
```

I have read about `$push` and `$addtoset`, but I think I miss the big picture about how aggregation works?

Thanks!

Comment: your output creates some confusion as per my understanding you should want to distinct `id_subcategory` and groups all `distinct session day wise` ?

Comment: your put it in better words than I :) exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS per my understanding I created some sample data set as follow :

```
db.collectionName.insert([{"session" : "870922750", "id_category" : 1118, "id_subcategory" : 2453, "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-15T12:31:55Z") },
{"session" : "870922750", "id_category" : 1118, "id_subcategory" : 2453, "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-15T12:31:55Z") },
{"session" : "870922750", "id_category" : 1118, "id_subcategory" : 2453, "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-16T12:31:55Z") },
{"session" : "870922751", "id_category" : 1118, "id_subcategory" : 2453, "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-16T12:31:55Z") },
{"session" : "870922751", "id_category" : 1118, "id_subcategory" : 2454, "date_created" : ISODate("2014-12-16T12:31:55Z") }])
```

Used [mong aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) and as per data set `date_created` is `ISODate` and from this `ISODate` find out `day` of given `date` so find out day use  [$dayOfMonth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#exp._S_dayOfMonth) in aggregation `$project` .

Aggregation query as :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "id_subcategory": 1,
    "session": 1,
    "day": {
      "$dayOfMonth": "$date_created" //find day of given ISODate
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "subCategory": "$id_subcategory", //groups subCategory, session and day 
      "session": "$session",
      "day": "$day"
    },
    "count": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": //this groups required to combining data 
  {
    "_id": "$_id.subCategory",
    "days": {
      "$push": {
        "day": "$_id.day",
        "count": "$count",
        "session": "$_id.session"
      }
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: yes, this is it. 
I see is important the order of $project, $group.... because I test it in other order and I get weird errors about "cannot convert from bson" etc. Thanks man for the quick answer.

Comment: what indexes shoud I have for best performance? excluding the ones for $match

Comment: better way to create index on `date_created` field